# get position of mouse on drop jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, draggable

using jQuery UI to for some drag and drop. I will have to tell if item is dropped outside of a div so I need to get the position of the mouse on stop, but it isn't working the way I had hoped.

here is what I have so far:

```
function getMouseXY() {
    var tempX, tempY;
    document.onmouseup = getMouseXY;
    function getMouseXY(e) {
        tempX = e.pageX
        tempY = e.pageY
        console.log("last xy: " + [tempX, tempY]);
        return [tempY, tempX];
    } 
}

var currentMousePosition = [];

$(".mcCirc").each(function(index){
    $(this).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        stop: function( event, ui) {
            currentMousePosition = getMouseXY();

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attaching the event when you have dropped when it should have been done before the drop action had happened.

It would have been better if you had included more example code :-)

Still I made an example:
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gYnbh/)

```
document.onmouseup = getMouseXY; // Attached too late.

var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

// This is better
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
    posX = e.pageX;
    posY = e.pageY;
});
```

Comment: ah, derp. I thought it would trigger as I drop it, but I guess that method gets called on mouseup too? that would make sense.